# Node + Express + Bookshelf

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I'm new to Node world. I want to build a Node+Express+Bookshelf (forget the front end for now). I'm following this [tutorial](http://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2014/12/16/building-a-simple-api-with-express-and-bookshelfjs).

But I want to refactor to what a Node structure looks like:

```
app/
    controller/
    models/
...
server.js
gruntFile.js
...
```

As I am still new to this world, I cannot figure out where the initialization goes,

```
Bookshelf.DB = Bookshelf.initialize({
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
        ....
    }
});
```

And how to write my model inside the `app/models/users.server.model.js` would go. This is what I have:

```
'use strict';

var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf').DB;

exports.model = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: "users",
});
```

And finally, how do I use my model in some other file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just include the files with the model in the controller, there is this node lib that basically let you include an entire folder
[include-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/include-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Bookshelf.Registry` plugin for that:

http://bookshelfjs.org/#Plugins-Registry

Then just require all your models and define them like this:

```
module.exports = bookshelf.model('MyModel', { ... });
```

To retrieve a model afterwards, do:

```
var MyModel = bookshelf.model('MyModel');
```